# Convert array of array of strings to a spark dataframe of array of strings in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a `string[][]` into a `Dataset<Row>` column consisting of `string[]`.
I have gone through the docs and available examples online but could not find something similar to this. I don't know if its possible or not as I'm a complete beginner in spark.

Sample input:
`String[][] test = {{"test1"}, {"test2", "test3"}, {"test4", "test5"}};`
Sample output:

```
Dataset<Row> test_df
test_df.show()
+-------------+
|          foo|
+-------------+
|      [test1]|
|[test2,test3]|
|[test4,test5]|
+-------------+
```

I'm probably defining the structType wrong for string[][], I've tried different ways too.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
    String[][] test = {{"test1"}, {"test2", "test3"}, {"test4", "test5"}};
    
    List<String[]> test1 = Arrays.asList(test);
    
    StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(
        DataTypes.createStructField(
                   "foo", 
                   DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType), 
                   true));
    
    Dataset<Row> t = spark.createDataFrame(test1, structType);
    t.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to use a method (`spark.createDataFrame(List<Row>, StructType)`) which takes a list of `Row` objects. But you use it with a list of arrays.

There are several ways to overcome it:

- Create a `Row` from each of the arrays, and then apply the method you have been using.
- Create a dataset of string arrays using a bean encoder and then convert it to a dataset of `Row` using a row encoder.
- Create the dataframe using a Java Bean.

I think the last method is the easiest, so here is how you do it. You have to define a small Java bean whose only instance variable is a String array.

```java
public static class ArrayWrapper {
    private String[] foo;

    public ArrayWrapper(String[] foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String[] getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String[] foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Make sure the Java Bean has a constructor that accepts a String array.

Then, to create the dataframe, you first create a list of `ArrayWrapper` (your Java Bean) from the array of arrays, and then make a dataframe using the `createDataFrame(List<?>,Class<?>)` method.

```java
String[][] test = {{"test1"}, {"test2", "test3"}, {"test4", "test5"}};
List<ArrayWrapper> list = Arrays.stream(test).map(ArrayWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
Dataset<Row> testDF = spark.createDataFrame(list,ArrayWrapper.class);
testDF.show();
```

The name of the column is determined by the name of the instance variable in the Java Bean.